# Is there any way I can make my code easier to understand and simpler?

Tags: python, optimization, pygame

I am wondering if by any chance there is a way to optimise this portion of my code. Regarding the pathing system and the redraw section. I find it really difficult to follow through it. Even changing the whole thing into a more understanding format will suit me. Thank you very much.

```
class wolf(object): #creating the wolf class

    wolf_right = ['pics/WR.png'] + ['pics/WR' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 18)] #identifies the right wolf pics
    wolf_left = ['pics/WL.png'] + ['pics/WL' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 18)] #identifies the left wolf pics

    run_right = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (280,160)) for img in wolf_right] #loads the right wolf pics
    run_left  = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (280,160)) for img in wolf_left] #load the left wolf pics

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, finish): #initialising the object wolf
        self.x = x #x coord of wolf
        self.y = y #y coord of wolf
        self.width = width #width of wolf
        self.height = height #height of wolf
        self.path = [x, finish]  # This part here determines the movement limits of the wolf, back and forth
        self.run_distance = 0 #wolf is initially did not move
        self.velocity = 9 #speed of wolf moving
        self.collision_box = (self.x + 60, self.y, 280, 160)#the arguments inside are the coordinates designating the sides of the box
                                                            #and then the width and the height of the box


    def pathing(self): #pathing system
        if self.velocity > 0:  # If wolf moving to the right
            if self.x < self.path[1] + self.velocity: #ensures that it keeps moving if wolf is not at finish
                self.x += self.velocity #allows wolf to move

            else: #if the finish is reached then go backwards
                self.velocity = self.velocity * -1 #where velocity goes negative
                                                   #according to displacement, a particle with -ve velocity goes backwards
                self.x += self.velocity #allows wolf to move


        else: # If wold is going to the left
            if self.x > self.path[0] - self.velocity: #ensures that it keeps moving if the wolf is not at finish
                self.x += self.velocity #allows wolf to move

            else: #if the finish is reached then go backwards
                self.velocity = self.velocity * -1 #where velocity goes negative
                                                   #according to displacement, a particle with -ve velocity goes backwards
                self.x += self.velocity #allows wolf to move

    def got_hit(self): #function if the wolf takes damage from the ninja
        print("Congrats, you have hit the wolf!")


    def redraw(self, win):#just like for the ninja we do the same steps
        self.pathing()
        if self.run_distance + 1 >= 51: #This time I am running 17 sprites thus, 17 * 3 (where 3 sprites per second)
            self.run_distance = 0

        if self.velocity < 0: #if velocity is increasing meaning movement, links left images with left movement
            win.blit(self.run_left[self.run_distance//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.run_distance += 1

        else:  #else linking right images with right movement
            win.blit(self.run_right[self.run_distance//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.run_distance += 1


        #pg.draw.rect(win, (0,200,0), self.collision_box,2) #this will draw a green box around the wolf of lines thickness 2
        self.collision_box = (self.x + 50 , self.y, 200, 150) # ensures the box is drawn and is updated alongside motion
```

Comment: [Codereview.se]

Comment: The code is not that complicated, but that's my opinion. I read it once through and it was easy to follow. Just one thing, `self.x += self.velocity` is done at the end of each of the 4 cases in `pathing`. It is sufficient to do it once at the end of `pathing`, instead of separately in each case. Similar for `self.run_distance += 1` in `redraw`.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not that complicated, but that's my opinion. I read it once through and it was easy to follow. Just one thing, `self.x += self.velocity` is done at the end of each of the 4 cases in `pathing`. It is sufficient to do it once at the end of `pathing`, instead of separately in each case. Something similar can be done for `self.run_distance += 1` in `redraw`:

```py
class wolf(object): #creating the wolf class

    # [...]

    def pathing(self): #pathing system

        if self.velocity > 0 and self.x >= self.path[1] + self.velocity or \
           self.velocity < 0 and self.x <= self.path[0] - self.velocity:
            self.velocity = self.velocity * -1
        self.x += self.velocity

    # [...]

    def redraw(self, win):#just like for the ninja we do the same steps
        self.pathing()
        if self.run_distance + 1 >= 51: #This time I am running 17 sprites thus, 17 * 3 (where 3 sprites per second)
            self.run_distance = 0

        run_surf = self.run_left if self.velocity < 0 else self.run_right
        win.blit(run_surf[self.run_distance//3], (self.x,self.y))
        self.run_distance += 1

        #pg.draw.rect(win, (0,200,0), self.collision_box,2) #this will draw a green box around the wolf of lines thickness 2
        self.collision_box = (self.x + 50 , self.y, 200, 150) # ensures the box is drawn and is updated alongside motion
```

---

Anyway in *pygame* it is intended to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).
Each Sprite should have the attributes `.rect` and `.image` and the method [`update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.update). The Sprites should be contained in Groups. The Groups can be drawn ([`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw)) and updated ([`update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update)).
That makes the code easy to read, short, comprehensible and extendable. e.g.:
([Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) should normally use the CapWords convention.)

```py
class Wolf(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    wolf_right = ['pics/WR.png'] + ['pics/WR' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 18)] #identifies the right wolf pics
    wolf_left = ['pics/WL.png'] + ['pics/WL' + str(i) + '.png' for i in range(2, 18)] #identifies the left wolf pics

    run_right = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (280,160)) for img in wolf_right] #loads the right wolf pics
    run_left  = [pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load(img), (280,160)) for img in wolf_left] #load the left wolf pics

    def __init__(self, x, y, finish):
        super().__init__():

        self.image = run_left[0]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 280, 160)
        self.path = [x, finish]  # This part here determines the movement limits of the wolf, back and forth
        self.run_distance = 0 #wolf is initially did not move
        self.velocity = 9 #speed of wolf moving
        self.collision_box = (self.rect.x + 60, self.rect.y, 280, 160) #the arguments inside are the coordinates designating the sides of the box
                                                            #and then the width and the height of the box

    def update(self, angle):

        if self.velocity > 0 and self.rect.x >= self.path[1] + self.velocity or \
           self.velocity < 0 and self.rect.x <= self.path[0] - self.velocity:
            self.velocity = self.velocity * -1
        self.rect.x += self.velocity

        if self.run_distance + 1 >= 51: #This time I am running 17 sprites thus, 17 * 3 (where 3 sprites per second)
            self.run_distance = 0

        run_surf = self.run_left if self.velocity < 0 else self.run_right
        if self.run_distance//3 > len(run_surf):
            self.run_distance = 0
        self.image = run_surf[self.run_distance//3]
        self.run_distance += 1

        self.collision_box = (self.rect.x + 50 , self.rect.y, 200, 150) # ensures the box is drawn and is updated alongside motion
```

```py
wolf = Wolf(........)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(wolf)

while True:

    # [...]

    all_sprites.update(win)

    # [...]

    all_sprites.draw(win)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was asking is there anyway to change the format of it? Like something different but yet still easy to understand

Comment: @Alucard what do you mean by "format"?

Comment: I mean how the code is written, e.g. another different way of writing it

Comment: @Alucard do you mean some kind of beautify? Sorry, but that is not a question about programming and off topic. Furthermore it is opinion based.